# Windows Server 2012 upgrade to R2 no logon servers available

Tags: windows-server-2012, upgrade

This is a VM running on ESXi 5.1
It was running Windows server 2012 and I upgraded in place to 2012 R2
It was being used primarily as a Remote Desktop Gateway

I ran the update, did some upgrades as requested, rebooted and ran the upgrade again. This time taking the defaults the upgrade worked without any hitches. The opening screen in the console in VMware for this vm indicates that it is Windows Server 2012 R2.

Using the vSphere Client in the console I log in with correct credentials or not doesn't matter and I get the following error "There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request"

I can log in to other systems on the same domain with so I don't think this is an issue with the DC - could be wrong.

Any ideas how to recover or avoid the problem next time i try this?

I am going to restore to my 2012 image from the backup tonight.

Comment: 1. `I ran the update, did some upgrades as requested, rebooted and ran the upgrade again` - This doesn't make sense. You had to run the upgrade twice? Why? 2. Did you verify that the VM is using the correct DNS servers?

Comment: I can't log in and I don't know how to check the dns otherwise. The server was setup with the correct DNS before I did the upgrade.

Comment: Can you log in with a local user account?

Comment: From the console, I am prompted for the password, the user name is filled in as the local administrator and I just hit the enter key - that is, no password, which is incorrect, and I get the error text as above.

Comment: I misspoke I haven't tried logging in with a local account I will now have to try that out with a test upgrade tomorrow. I just restored my 2012 server in order to get it back online.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized, and the OP has already rolled back, making any answer given simply a guess at this point.  Better to just delete the question and ask again if it comes back up.

Comment: I am now in the middle of attempting same upgrade on same OS after doing a similar upgrade i.e. 2012 to 2012 R2 but in this case it was an application server. In that case I did do a local admin log on and was able to restore the fixed IP address as noted in the answer below. Once I finish the upgrade of the OS that prompted this question I'll mark the answer or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to logon using a local Administrator. An in-place upgrade from 2012 to 2012 R2 has the habit of losing IP Address assignments that you did. (Had that on all of my boxes)

After setting a correct IP Address, you should be able to login with domain credentials.

Comment: I did a restore to the 2012 version after this error to get it back on line. Today I performed the in place upgrade and at the end I attempted to log in with the Domain credentials and it failed as described in the original post. Then I logged in as the local Administrator. Fixed up the IP address and I am now in the process of verifying that the RD Gateway is functioning properly.